# How to automatically change the frequency of CPU?

Tags: server

I'm trying to make a server using the Ubuntu Server Operating System and I don't want the CPU to be always at a high frequency, just so that I can save some money on my electricity bill.

I want it to work at low frequency if there is no load, and high frequency if there is load on the server.

Comment: Your CPUs should be frequency scaling up and down as a function of load by default. They should also be going into deeper and shallower idle states as a function of work / sleep frequencies by default. For example, my test server processor consumes 1.4 watts when idle and throttles to 125 watts under the prime95 highest energy torture test, all automatically.

Comment: This ^^^ There's really really no need for what you think is solution to a non-problem.

Answer (score 1):

there is a package "cpulimit" you can use to limit the cpu percentage on specific processes that consume too much resources

after installing it with

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install cpulimit
```

you can use it to limit resource consumption of either 1- a process (by ID) or 2- a process (by the executable's name) or 3- a path using -p, -e and -P respectively.

these examples are from the manual:

```
cpulimit -e foo -l 50
              limits  the CPU usage of the process by acting on the executable
              program file (note: the argument "--bar" is omitted)

cpulimit -p 1234 -l 50
              limits the CPU usage of the process by acting  on  its  PID,  as
              shown by ps(1)

cpulimit -P /usr/bin/foo -l 50
              same as -e but uses the absolute path name
```

Comment: Ambiguity detected, I guess `-e foo` names the "the process" `foo`

Comment: thanks @Hannu I edited the answer